# N-tier navigation in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to create top navigation in code-igniter?

Answer (score 0):

In controller I have declare a function and call model

```
private function getNavigation(){
    $this->load->model('xx');
    $data['nav'] = $this->xx->prepareTree();
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

And In model I have declare three functions

```
public function prepareTree(){
    $this->db->select("`catalog_parent` as parent_id, `catalog_name` as menu_item, `catalog_id` as id, `catalog_template` as pager_id");
    $this->db->from("catalog_category");
    $this->db->where("`catalog_navigation` = '1'");
    $this->q = $this->db->get();
    $create = '';
    if ($this->q->num_rows() > 0) {
       $create = $this->prepareList($this->q->result_array());
    }
    if(!empty($create)){
        return $this->category_tree($create);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
 }

 private function prepareList(array $items, $pid = 0) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ((int) $item['parent_id'] == $pid) {
            if ($children = $this->prepareList($items, $item['id'])) {
                $item['children'] = $children;
            }
            $output[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

private function category_tree($menu_items, $child = false){
    $output = '';
    if (count($menu_items)>0) {
        $output .= ($child === false) ? '<ul id="main-menu" class="sm sm-blue">' : '<ul>' ;

        foreach ($menu_items as $item) {
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= '<a href="#">'.$item['menu_item'].'</a>';
            if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
                $output .= $this->category_tree($item['children'], true);
            }
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

If some suggest an more easy way please suggest us.
Thanks